# Retornar registros categorias/subcategorias PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas e registros:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_categoria` text,
  `titulo` text,
  `referencia` text,
  `valor` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagem_principal` text,
  `descricao` text,
  `data` text,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `produto` (`id`, `id_categoria`, `titulo`, `referencia`, `valor`, `imagem_principal`, `descricao`, `data`, `status`) VALUES
(1, '5', '4Y1A7316-S169', '4Y1A7316-S169', '0', 'd6663aa43c2c044e90375d312b601599.png', '<p>Pincel para Cílios&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>', '2019-04-17 18:02:24', 0),
(2, '5', '5Y1A7316-S621', '5Y1A7316-S621', '0', '7f699d3c34fd63b8810b1a457404c317.png', '<p>5Y1A7316-S621<br></p>', '2019-04-22 17:47:24', 0);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produto_categoria` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_categoria` text,
  `titulo` text,
  `ordem` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;


INSERT INTO `produto_categoria` (`id`, `id_categoria`, `titulo`, `ordem`) VALUES
(1, '0', 'Cílios', '0'),
(2, '0', 'Pentes', '2'),
(3, '0', 'Toucas', '4'),
(4, '1', 'Fio a Fio', '0'),
(5, '1', '3D', '1'),
(6, '0', 'Pinças', '0'),
(7, '0', 'Pincéis', '0'),
(8, '0', 'Tesouras', '0'),
(9, '0', 'Unhas', '0'),
(10, '0', 'Esponjas', '0'),
(11, '0', 'Espátula', '0'),
(12, '0', 'Alicates', '0');
```

Note que eu tenho dois registros na tabela produto, com id_categoria 5. Subcategoria que pertence a categoria cílios (1).

Preciso elaborar um SQL onde eu consiga trazer os registros, independentemente da subcategeoria. 
Neste caso, preciso que o resultado retorne os dois produtos, quando eu selecionar categoria 1.

Meu SQL Atual segue abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM `produto` 
LEFT JOIN `produto_categoria` ON `produto_categoria`.`id`=`produto`.`id_categoria` 
WHERE `produto_categoria`.`id` = '1'`
```

Dessa forma, eu buscaria somente os produtos da categoria = 1, mas existem variáveis dentro dessa categoria, como eu consigo retornar?

Criei no SQL FILDDLE: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/916cba/1

Comment: Na regra do seu sistema, os produtos podem ter um `id_categoria` que não é uma subcategoria? Ex: id_categoria = 1

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

A query abaixo retorna os produtos que sejam da categoria 1 ou cujos produtos sejam de uma categoria filha(1 nível) da categoria 1.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM produto p
left JOIN produto_categoria cat 
ON cat.id = p.id_categoria or cat.id_categoria = p.id_categoria;
```